# How to reset Mac keyboard custom mappings using DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, default-settings

Hello I recently wanted to do a custom mapping for my home/end keys to match the windows style behavior.  Unfortunately,  this also remapped my copy/paste keys.  I'd like to revert this.

I mapped the keys by setting the DefaultKeyBinding.dict file with some mappings I found online :

```
mkdir -p $HOME/Library/KeyBindings
echo '{
/* Remap Home / End keys to be correct */
"\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; /* Home */
"\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLine:"; /* End */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + End */
"^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + Home */
"^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + End */
"$^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + Home */
"$^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + End */
}' > $HOME/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Does anyone know how I can reset these values back to their default?  I'd like to just use the default Mac mappings.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just removing the folder you created & rebooting? It doesn't exist by default, so if it's something the OS looks for at boot, it then won't find anything to remap.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the DefaultKeyBinding.dict file and remove all those lines.

Here's a way to do it...

- From finder, select `Go` -> `Go to Folder`
- type `~/Library` and head into that folder
- Find the `KeyBindings` folder and enter it
- See `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and open it (Text Edit is fine)
- Either delete the entire file, or just delete the lines you have above, save,
- reboot

This should work.